# How to get Path of Binding of a DataGridBoundColumn

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a simple datagrid to which I am binding a collection using ItemsSource. In my c# code I wan't to retrieve binding path of a column. I have reference to the column. Here is the non-working code that I have put up

```
DataGridBoundColumn column = getColumn() //function to get column. Already working
BindingBase binding = column.Binding;  //get the binding
PropertyPath path = //how to get the path from binding.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to downcast to "Binding". Then you can access the path.

Answer (score 3):

Example from Martin's answer.

```
//Ex: In xaml <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding column1}"/>

foreach (DataGridBoundColumn c in myGrid.Columns)
{
    Binding b = (Binding)c.Binding; //Two different binding types.  
    MessageBox.Show(b.Path.Path); //Returns "column1".  
}
```